# Were there 27 more Buddhas before Siddhartha Gautam Buddha?

Tags: early-buddhism

Were there 27 more Buddhas before Siddhartha Gautam Buddha? If so, are there any evidences of it. How about the finding of Buddhist *Stupas* and Idols in Harappa civilization?Is it linked with this fact?

Comment: kindly please refer to [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/2627/how-many-buddhas-are-there/2634#2634)

Comment: Endless before and endless to come, consider infinite space/time and the cyclical/dynamic/(I-change, I-ching 易經) of the cosmos(es). For instant, 大通智勝佛 (Buddha MahaPrajna?) spent 10 Kalpas in Samadhi to acquire the Buddha Dharma is one other than the 27.

Answer (score 3):

**Were there 27 more Buddhas before Siddhartha Gautam Buddha?**

Yes, the Buddha speaks of them in his suttas, many of them from different times/planets throughout the universe(s).

**If so, are there any evidences of it.**

Other than the suttas themselves, yes in various other religious traditions.

**How about the finding of Buddhist Stupas and Idols in Harappa civilization? Is it linked with this fact?**

Yes it could be but rather than spending our lifetime endlessly trying to settle historical matters and learn other histories, let us be grateful for what the Gautama Buddha has provided us: a complete, methodical practice towards Enlightenment. We will need to devote whatever spare time aside from job and other duties to achieve what he achieved and the Buddhas after him (Padmasambhava). The other Buddhisms that stemmed from Hinayana Buddhism suggest there is a greater journey towards Complete Enlightenment and complete power, even after initial srotipanna and escaping the force of rebirth.
No need to excavate skeletons--it was hard enough for the Buddha to leave behind what he has and those after him.

Comment: The teaching/practice is more important than history, agree. Unless one developed the Iddhi ability to know directly, else history is just another one telling his version of the story. However, I wonder if Padmasambhava should be regarded as - in the official sequential of Buddhas in our Loka? Padma. is Bud. Shakyamuni in some tradition. Sutra 《佛説千佛因緣經》translated Kumarajiva, few pages only, lists thousand Buddhas and the previous Buddha Dipamkara etc. with very interesting accounts of them.

Comment: Please quote all of these suttas where the Buddha speaks of past Buddhas. Thanks

Comment: @Dhammadhatu If someone convicted to a dictionary that has only collection of A to D the rest E to Z missing, it's futile to reconcile the knowledge on E to Z; Sutra name provided in previous comment. Buddha Dipamkara must have been mentioned in the Pali Sutta as if words of C shared among these two dictionaries. Buddha 樓至 doesn't, same as words of K can't be found in one of the dictionaries.

Comment: @Dhammadhatu It's better to be a Buddhavacana-mysophobe than the fanatics though. Fanatics were the material used by the ambitious to trumpet the Crusade/Holy War. Fanatics lose their mind of discern, the elementary instruction of the Buddha to his students. Even the lame Wikipedia has collected some insights on *pre-sectarian Buddhism* http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-sectarian_Buddhism, read those others with discern, than believed in blind faith on the promoted Theosophist Edward Conze's.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there were three Buddha's before Gautam Buddha and they were all historical persons . If you read the travel record of Fahian and huen tsang they clearly write that we have visited the stupa of Kakusandh Buddha , and Kassapa Buddha .  King Asok in his Nigliwa inscription write "here at this place I doubled the size of stupa of Konagaman Buddha " . This is a very clear Indication that Kakusandh Buddha , Konagaman Buddha , Kassapa Buddha were real historical persons and this fact link Buddhist religion with Indus Valley .

Answer (score -4):

Personally, I do not believe there were any Buddhas before Gotama.

This is why there is probably no evidence.

The idea of past Buddhas is found only a few suttas among thousands, where, in those suttas, the technology mentioned, such as chariot-making or potting, was the same as in the Buddha's time.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60174/discussion-on-answer-by-dhammadhatu-were-there-27-more-buddhas-before-siddhartha).